# Matlab exit force with return code greater than zero

Tags: matlab, jenkins

I've a Matlab R2007b script which I call from a batch script like this:

```
   matlab.exe -nosplash -nodesktop -r my_script
```

I've a try/catch block in the Matlab script and on error it runs exit(1), to indicate to the calling process (indirectly, Jenkins!) that the process has failed.

This works great except occasionally on exit via error Matlab wants to save any modified files and pops up a save dialogue (not great when you're running headless with Jenkins!).  I can avoided this with a 'exit force' but then my return code is always 0 (indicating success to Jenkins).

Is it possible in Matlab to force exit AND set a return code greater than zero?

```
   exit(1) force
```

Comment: What happens with the return code? If it gets written to a file or saved somewhere you could do it directly in the catch statement and then just use force.

Comment: The return code is used by the parent batch script to send fail/success emails to the user.  I'm thinking a way round this is for Matlab to write its status to a file and then batch to read it.

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried to figure out a solution to this issue. Since working with environment variables did not work out the way we wanted, I created a workaround with a dummy file that is created whenever the Matlab call fails and then checked in Jenkins (currently no Matlab access, maybe some quotes are wrong):

```
matlab -r "try, [returnVal]=ScriptName;catch, disp('exception occurred']); returnVal= -1; end, if (returnVal~= 0), fid = fopen('errorFile.txt','wt'); fclose(fid); end, exit force"

IF EXIST errorFile.txt (exit /b 1)
```

Generally, of course, it also makes sense to include additional arguments in the matlab call, for Windows, e.g.:

```
matlab -log -nosplash -nodesktop -noFigureWindows -minimize -wait
```